# REPORTING SERVICES: TABLIX DON'T FILTER

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, reporting-services, filter, reporting

Today I have a problem with a table in reporting services.

I have a project with ASP.NET and I'm using reporting services with SQL server.

I have a report with a table and a graphic to show the information, the data set query is:

```
SELECT ID, USER, DATE, TYPE
FROM USER_TABLE
WHERE (TYPE LIKE CASE WHEN @TYPE IS NULL THEN '' ELSE @TYPE END + '%')
```

I have a parameter that is called `TYPE` like the field, is allow null values.

And I added the parameter in the table properties in the `Filters` section :

```
[@TYPE] = [TYPE]
```

My problem is when I run the report the parameter It´s in null option en doesn't show the records and no one information....

Just if I write something in parameter filter properly...

How can I solve this?

Comment: Instead of setting @Type as a filter on the Tablix, you should set it as a parameter on your dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the default value of the Parameter to NULL

[image]

Comment: Yes, I already tried add that setting, and the result is exactly the same :S